# Can I have multiple psudeo's on css?

Tags: css

So I have been trying a code so like `.randomClass:hover:active` so Like thats a button if you hover over it it will change the background color and if you click it it will do the same thing, and I don't wanna repeat the same thing for example `.randomClass:hover{Background-color: green;} .randomClass:active{}` I don't wanna do that.

Comment: `.randomClass:hover:active {}` will target the element when it's _both_ hovered **and** active.  `.randomClass:hover, .randomClass:active {}` will target it when it's _either_ hovered **or** active.  Is this what you are asking?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you could do something like

```
.randomClass:hover,
.randomClass:active {
/* style */
}
```

Comment: Right, I forget you could do multiple selectors in CSS. Thanks!